# Is "have/has lead to" OK?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I found [a set of examples](http://www.just-the-word.com/show_examples.pl?triple=lead_N%20obj_of%20have_V%5Eto_PREP) where I expect *led* instead of *lead*.

> In recent years the rise in the crime rate has lead to increased concern on the part of both the police and the general public.

While these are just a few examples the number of results on a Google search is impressively high:

- [*have lead to*](https://www.google.de/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=%22has%20lead%20to%22&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#sclient=psy-ab&hl=de&client=opera&hs=obQ&rls=en&channel=suggest&q=%22have%20lead%20to%22&oq=%22have%20lead%20to%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i19.3718.3953.0.4133.3.3.0.0.0.0.79.205.3.3.0...0.0...1c.CN2ainXyejw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=a6669836e43754f4&biw=1680&bih=941) (8,850,000 hits)
- [*has lead to*](https://www.google.de/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=%22has%20lead%20to%22&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#sclient=psy-ab&hl=de&client=opera&hs=BHl&rls=en&channel=suggest&q=%22has%20lead%20to%22&oq=%22has%20lead%20to%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i19l2j0i5i19.149715.150049.2.150136.3.3.0.0.0.0.138.295.2j1.3.0...0.0...1c._QxoXp5yPHo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=a6669836e43754f4&biw=1680&bih=941) (22,000,000 hits)

I pondered if using *have lead to* could mean that someone "has a lead position" and the preposition *to* introduces a comparison, i.e. subordinate person. But I don't think so. At least the cited example and the sentences in the link contain typos or even grammatical errors.

Hence I wonder if there is any specific in *have/has lead to* or if just too many people don't know that the past participle of *lead* is *led*?

Comment: It's probably a spelling mistake as none of the dictionaries list *lead* but *led* as the past and past participle of *lead*. So it should be *led* not *lead*.

Comment: "could of" has 43.5 million hits according to Google ( http://tinyurl.com/7h96tsy ). I wouldn't be impressed by search engine stats if I were you :) You might find Google Trends a more meaningful use of your time ( http://tinyurl.com/cxyen87 )

Comment: It's probably just a spelling mistake, based on the conjugation *read, read, have read* (which rhyme with *lead, led, have led*, *plead, pled, have pled*). Note that *have plead* also has a large number of Google hits.

Comment: @PeterShor I think so, too. Snailboat already mentioned that in another comment. Unfortunately, nobody has given this as an answer yet.

Comment: The error of using "has lead to" or "has lead [an organization]" may be as common as it is because Microsoft's grammar checker doesn't catch it.

Answer (score 5):

It should be 'led'.

[verb (past and past participle led /lɛd/)](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lead)

The confusion is that the soft grey metal they used to make pipes out of is spelled 'lead', but pronounced 'led'.

Comment: You think the problem occurs because people confuse leadership with lead pipes?  That's definitely a fringe conspiracy theory.

Comment: I think the problem occurs because two words sound the same and have similar spelling. Where is the conspiracy in that?

Comment: It's also possible the confusion comes from association with 'read', which has the past and past participle 'read' rather than 'red'.

Answer (score -1):

It should say "have led," but, given rapid demise of irregular verb forms, I am grateful if it does not say, "have leaded."

Comment: By rapid, you mean the movement between the weak and strong forms that have been happening over the last 1,000 years?

Comment: Since *pleaded* is currently changing to *pled*, I don't see why *led* should be simultaneously changing to *leaded*.